# Detecting circle using hough transformation

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I was trying to detect the coins in an given image to draw vertical line or grouping the coins which falls under the same straight line.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = Image.open("coin.jpg")
imgUMat = np.float32(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgUMat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#plt.imshow(img)
#gray = (np.float32(imgUMat), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.resize(gray,None,fx=0.25, fy=0.25, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

img = cv2.medianBlur(gray,1)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
              param1=30,
              param2=15,
              minRadius=0,
              maxRadius=0)
#circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,100,param1=100,param2=1)
if (circles!=None):
    i = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    cv2.circle(gray,(i[0,0,0],i[0,0,1]),i[0,0,2],(255,255,255),1)
    cv2.circle(gray,(i[0,0,0],i[0,0,1]),1,(255,255,255),1)
    center_x.append(i[0,0,0])
    center_y.append(i[0,0,1])
```

***When I ran the code, I got an error at circles variable saying that,***

> error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:1728: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'

Comment: It looks like your image is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read your image with opencv instead of pil.

It would look like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray = cv2.imread('coin.png', 0) # The zero reads the image in gray scale
gray = cv2.resize(gray,None,fx=0.25, fy=0.25, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

img = cv2.medianBlur(gray,1)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray,1)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20,
              param1=30,
              param2=15,
              minRadius=0,
              maxRadius=0)

print (circles)
```

I am not sure what you want to do in your if statement. But I think you should also change this since center_x and center_y are not defined.
HoughCircles will also return a Numpy array, therefore you can not use `!= None` I think this works better.

```
center_x, center_y = [], []
if (len(circles) > 0):
    i = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    cv2.circle(gray,(i[0,0,0],i[0,0,1]),i[0,0,2],(255,255,255),1)
    cv2.circle(gray,(i[0,0,0],i[0,0,1]),1,(255,255,255),1)
    center_x.append(i[0,0,0])
    center_y.append(i[0,0,1])
```